# SetParameter of a source

Tags: anylogic

I have the following problem: My model must be fed by a fixed number of patients per day. Specifically, three patients must arrive every 11 minutes from 8am to 6pm! I have set the source block in the "Interarrival" mode which allows me to define the interval between patients and to have three patients every 11 min; To block the arrival of patients at 6pm I have created an event which resets the patients arrival rate to zero! But the next morning how can I set again all the specifications for the source block through an event?

Comment: Your other comments show that you need your arrivals to be 3 *exactly* every 11 mins (not *on average* 3 every 11 mins). You should make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the inject function instead of interarrival mode.

You are on the right track by using an event. Set the event as cyclic with a cycle time of 11 minutes. The action would be:

```
if( getHourOfDay() >= 8 &&  getHourOfDay() <= 18 )
source.inject(3);
```

Below are some images to guide you further:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Using this method, however, it is not certain that patients will arrive at 8, they may have a delay of 11 min given by the event cycle! right?

Comment: To resolve this, you can specify the first occurrence to be an exact date and time. For example, instead of 0 seconds, choose the start date of your model and time 8. This way you'll know that the first ones will arrive at time 8, and then every 11 min from there.

Comment: Doesn't work! It's only on time the first day! There isn't a way to set the parameters for the source by an event??

Comment: yes, this is because I needed both an interarrival time and a rate of three at each arrival! OK, thank u! if I wanted to add an hour of lunch break I would have to modify the intervals specified for the function inject()??

Comment: You'll need to add an extra condition in the if like if( getHourOfDay() >= 8 &&  getHourOfDay() <= 1 || getHourOfDay() >= 2 &&  getHourOfDay() <= 18 )

Comment: yes, but with the schedules I can't set exactly 3 arrivals every 11 minutes! I don't want there to be any kind of distribution, but only three arrivals every 11 min!

Comment: || means or if you are not familiar with the syntax. I also see your point, you want every day the arrivals to start at 8:00 AM exactly. I'll tell you how to fix that.

Comment: Okay, here is another thing you can do. Create another event that starts at the same time but with a cycle of 1 day. Write in the action field: event.restart(0); That way, you will know that your first event (called event) will be scheduled to start at exactly 8:00 AM every day. That should address what you need. Right?